# App is crashing while running AVD in Android Studio. I am running on virtual device pixel 5x with API 27

Tags: android-studio, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

When I try to create and instance of FusedLocationApi it doesn't get recognized some How. it is in red. It is not importing any classes. seems to me that there might be some problem in Gradle Build App. Please Check it out.

This is My MapActivity.java File

```
package com.matt.mapapp;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements             
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,     
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient client;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       String[] permissions,
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

}
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    client.connect();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        LocationRequest.FusedLocationApi.requestlocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

This is my build gradle (Module app) File. There seemed to be some problem in compiling as there is no such command as compile

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 26
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.matt.mapapp"
           minSdkVersion 22
           targetSdkVersion 26
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner               
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        
'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
       androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

please Check it out and tell me the reason behind. I was following a video tutorial on how to create a map based app and suddenly when I reached at a point to use Fused Location Api I got stuck. The Build Gradle code in the tutorial was different than mine so I thing that this can be the reason for the FusedLocationApi to not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a app based on the Google map never use virtual device as it gives error most of the times rather you should connect to an android phones with usb debugging on. For that you would have to go to about section of the phone's setting and click on build version or build number for 7 or the number of times it say you require in order to become a developer than go back to main settings and click on developer option from there you would have to turn on USB debugging. Now your phone would ask a connection verification to PC click accept and tick remember my choice. Now you would be able to see your phone above all the listed virtual devices and you would be able to install the app in your phone. Thnaks.

Let me know if that helped you...

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me and also very thank you for the guide of USB debugging I appreciate that.